# characteristic polynomial based on differential equation

Tags: programming, differential-equations, replacement

I have this differential equation:

$$\ddot{x}-\frac{1}{6} \dot{x} - \frac{1}{6}x = e^t$$

When I DSolve it looks like this:

```
DSolve[x''[t] - 1/6 x'[t] - 1/6 x[t] == Exp[t], x[t], t]
```

Which gives me the correct answer. With that, we know I have the characteristic polynomial:

```
z^2 - 1/6 z - 1/6
```

I also find the roots:

```
Root[%,1]
Root[%%,2]
```

So all the results are correct. My question is, how can make this more easy for me, so I don't need to type manually the characteristic polynomial with its roots?
I have tried with the function StringReplace to rewrite my differential equation into the characteristic polynomial, but it was messy and not functioning properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the ODE

```
ode=x''[t] - 1/6*x'[t] - 1/6*x[t] == Exp[t]
```

to get the characteristic polynomial we follow the literature:

```
cpoly = Simplify[(ode[[1]]/.x->(Exp[r*#]&))/Exp[r*t]]
```

now we calculate the roots:

```
{Root[cpoly,1], Root[cpoly,2]}
```

or

```
Solve[cpoly==0, r]
```

Also for the odes of the form

```
 ode=t^2*x''[t] - 1/6*t*x'[t] - 1/6 x[t] == Exp[t]
```

the only change is on the substitution:

```
cpoly2 = Simplify[(ode[[1]]/.x->(#^r&))/t^r]
```

Finally, if you want to have the multiplicity of the root handy you can use `Tally`:

Tally[Solve[cpoly==0, r]//Flatten]

Comment: what if the characteristic polynomial has a different number of roots than 2? It might have 1, 3 or 4?

Comment: Thats why I gave also `Solve`.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
t1 = x''[t] - x'[t]/6 - x[t]/6 /. {Derivative[k_Integer][x][__] :> z^k, x[__] :> 1}
   -1/6 - z/6 + z^2

t2 = x'''[t] - 5 x'[t]/6 - 3 x[t] /. {Derivative[k_Integer][x][__] :> z^k, x[__] :> 1}
   -3 - 5 z/6 + z^3
```

Then,

```
z /. Solve[t1 == 0, z]
   {-1/3, 1/2}


z /. Solve[t2 == 0, z, Cubics -> False]
   {Root[-18 - 5 #1 + 6 #1^3 &, 1], Root[-18 - 5 #1 + 6 #1^3 &, 2],
    Root[-18 - 5 #1 + 6 #1^3 &, 3]}
```

Remove `Cubics -> False` to see the actual Cardano solution.

Comment: Thank you. But it only answer half of my question. It doesn't write the roots.
`{Root[%, 1], Root[%, 2]}`could be added the line under. However I don't have 2 roots every time.  Other times I have 1, 3 or 4.